# Allow use of system python in conda env?

Tags: python, conda, package-management

Is there a way to force conda to use the system version of python (along with all of the system libraries) in a given env?

I have conda enabled by default in my shell, which can get a bit annoying, because if I try to run a system python app, it gets a different version of python to what it is expecting (python still defaults to 2.7 on *buntu), and often won't run. I would like the root env of conda to just be a redirect to the system python install.

Comment: Could you give an example app/experience, I've not seen this.

Comment: @AndyHayden: I'm using python 3.4 in my conda root env, and so basically any ubuntu package that has `!#/bin/env python` at the start of the main script will fail if run from the command line (because it's expecting python 2, which is still the default). My `.profile` and `.zshrc` both have the lines `# added by Miniconda3 3.9.1 installer ; export PATH="/home/naught101/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"` in them, so conda is enabled in all shells by default.

Comment: Do you think this a bug in these applications? What applications? Can you install that application with conda (rather than apt-get)?

Comment: @AndyHayden: Every python-based package installed via apt that doesn't specify a python version. Try `grep -Hn 'env python' /usr/bin/*`. For example `fslint-gui`. Yes, it's probably better that those packages specify the python version, but I suspect that there are a lot of packages that don't in the ubuntu repos, on the basis that python2 is default and can be expected.  I feel like it should be possible to completely disable conda, and use only the system python install. I guess I could probably just `/home/naught101/miniconda3/bin/python`, but I'm not sure if that has other consequences.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit all user shell run commands such as your .bashrc file to prepend the bin directory of anaconda to path `export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH`, while in your root run commands append `export PATH=$PATH:~/anaconda/bin`. In both cases you will have access to the `conda` command. You can check which python will be run by typing `$env python --version`. You can also check which other versions would be available and their order of priority (if the other is removed) by using `$type -a python`. Of course ensure your executable python files have `#!/usr/bin/env python` and not some other direct route to a python executable. For further info Google BASH Shell look up queries like http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/an-example-how-shell-understand-which-program-to-run-part-ii.html.

Comment: @naught101, I do believe what is explained above would work: if you edit the run commands that are executed under the root user so that the exported PATH reads `export PATH="$PATH:/home/naught101/miniconda3/bin"` (they would reside under both root and user's home via `$cd ~` ), any file/script/etc that is executed under root would look up the default python before your conda version as explained and you should be able to verify using the methods above.

Comment: Yeah, it does make the system python default when a shell starts, which is good, but if you `source activate blah` and then `source deactivate`, then the conda root env python becomes the default again, until you restart the shell.

Comment: @naught101 you may try this: `export PATH=$(conda ..deactivate)`

Answer (score 1):

Simply removing the `python` symlink from `~/miniconda3/bin/` appears to do the job.

```
$ which python           
/home/naught101/miniconda3/bin/python
$ rm /home/naught101/miniconda3/bin/python
$ which python                            
/usr/bin/python
$ source activate science                 
discarding /home/naught101/miniconda3/bin from PATH
prepending /home/naught101/miniconda3/envs/science/bin to PATH
(science)$ which python           
/home/naught101/miniconda3/envs/science/bin/python
(science)$ source deactivate                       
discarding /home/naught101/miniconda3/envs/science/bin from PATH
$ which python     
/usr/bin/python
```

So far, this doesn't seem to have caused me any problems. Unfortunately the same doesn't work for `~/miniconda/bin/python3`, because conda requires it when switching to other envs that use the same python version. However, that one hasn't caused as many problems in the first place.

If this *does* cause problems, it's easy enough to undo, just `cd ~/miniconda/bin/; ln -s python3 python` (or what ever version of python you're using in your conda root env). You may need to activate/deactivate an env to get that version of python back on your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in (base) or another environment, use `conda deactivate`, this will exit conda's environment and place you back into the OS environment:

on MacOS

```
(base) user$ python --version
Python 3.9.12
(base) user$ conda deactivate
user$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

on Linux (with no base python installed)

```
(base) user$ python --version
Python 3.9.15
(base) user$ conda deactivate
user$ python --version
-bash: python: command not found
```