# Can you create a miniconda environment from macOS native Python?

Tags: python, macos, miniconda

*ORIGINAL POST:*

I have a project that is requiring me to use underlying macOS install of Python 2.7.10 (it is a matter of how it was compiled).  Is there a way to actually use the native macOS Python in the creation of a miniconda environment or is the only thing available to virtualenv the native Python?  For example, `conda create -n whatever python=2.7.10` will not work for what I am working with.

*EDIT:*

Is there any way to use the native macOS installed version of Python (in this case, 2.7.10 found in '/usr/bin/python'), when creating a new conda env (vs. pulling from miniconda's repos)?  The particular vendor app I am working with, has modules expecting to see the specific compiled version, from Apple.  I.e., it is not sufficient enough to `conda create -n whatever python=2.7.10`.  I'm guessing this would be some kinda' clone exercise, if exists.  If not used, errors (ex. below)

Thinking my only alternative is to virtualenv the native macOS python env.  Meaning, I can use conda for most projects, but if I am working with something that has to be "native"... `conda deactviate` from base, and (as example) `source native/bin/activate` the 2.7.10 env.

```
(test2) $ 
(test2) $ python test.py
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
(test2) $ conda deactivate
(base) $ conda deactivate
$ source ~/virtualenvs/native/bin/activate
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
(native) $ python test.py
pe2
c12
pe14
c15
pe13
pe10
pe11
pe3
p6
p7
p4
p5
c1
p8
p9
(native) $
```

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. `conda` actually works with various programming languages, not just Python. Hopefully someone with experience will be able to chime in

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do this. Anaconda deliberately compile Python and the dependencies with the same compiler toolchain to minimize compatibility errors. If you give a description of what you're trying to do, we might be able to help.

Comment: juanpa, Thank you and undertsand that conda can be flexible in language (beyond Python) and version.
darthbith, I think you are following what I am asking -- and I am not finding anything that looks like you can do, either.  Please see the edited version of the OP.

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I guess you could suggest that, but with the edit I'm trying to show/clarify my question and give further example.  The vendor code works with macOS supplied Python, not with a repo version of the same rev.  Yes, I can craft a solution to my problem, outside of conda.  Fundamentally, the question remains: does conda only use repo-ed version of Python in creation of environments?  Alternately, anyway to solve this, all in the context of conda?

Comment: I don't know then. Maybe [Allow use of system python in conda env?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872316/allow-use-of-system-python-in-conda-env) can help, but it does not look clean.